HID Telephony Device Usage ID "Host Call Active" Not Changing When Start/Stop Online Meetings
Trying to create an HID device that can detect when an online meeting (such as Skype, Google Meet, Zoom) starts and ends. Trying to utilize the Telephony Device output report to make that possible, since the HID documentation has a Telephony Usage ID called Host Call Active (0xF2) that seems like a close match to what I need. Some details below.
As a test with an HID keyboard device, I'm able to detect output reports on using the sample descriptor. For example, if I set CAPS LOCK active manually from my pc (and not my HID keyboard), then my device will detect that a tud_hid_set_report_cb has been called to show that data has been sent from the host to the device (since the caps lock data was set by the host pc).
I was able to setup a HID telephony device type and set one output report description. In this case, I want to detect if the host pc starts and stops a meeting. I see in the HID documentation that there is actually a telephony device usage ID for this, called host call active (0xF2). However, when I start a zoom meeting or google meeting, I do not detect any tud_hid_set_report_cb to show that the host is currently in a call.
I have my custom HID descriptor here. Do you know if there is anything that looks wrong here? If nothing looks wrong, am I missing any steps? Maybe the host call active usage ID is not applicable to online meetings? Thanks in advance.
#define TUD_HID_REPORT_DESC_TELEPHONY(...) \
  HID_USAGE_PAGE ( HID_USAGE_PAGE_TELEPHONY )                     ,\
  HID_USAGE      ( 5 )                  ,\
  HID_COLLECTION ( HID_COLLECTION_APPLICATION )                   ,\
    /* Report ID if any */\
    __VA_ARGS__ \
    /* Host Call Active */ \
    HID_USAGE_PAGE ( HID_USAGE_PAGE_TELEPHONY )                    ,\
      /* 242 is the Host Call Active Usage ID */
      HID_USAGE      ( 242 )      ,\ 
      HID_LOGICAL_MIN( 0                                      )    ,\
      HID_LOGICAL_MAX( 1                                      )    ,\
      HID_REPORT_COUNT( 1                                      )    ,\
      HID_REPORT_SIZE ( 1                                      )    ,\
      HID_OUTPUT      ( HID_DATA | HID_VARIABLE | HID_ABSOLUTE )    ,\
      /* 7 bit padding */ \
      HID_REPORT_COUNT( 1                                      )    ,\
      HID_REPORT_SIZE ( 7                                      )    ,\
      HID_OUTPUT      ( HID_CONSTANT                           )    ,\
  HID_COLLECTION_END \

Tried testing out output report functionality with HID keyboards to make sure I knew how output reports were obtained, which worked.
For the desc_configuration, Tried using both the TUD_HID_DESCRIPTOR and TUD_HID_INOUT_DESCRIPTOR templates to make sure that it wasn't a lack of EP OUT issue.
